# Cant see value of the variable while debugging even all setting is correct?

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, debugging, ide

I am trying to debug Python2.7 to understand more about how python works.

when I trying to debug ceval.c at line 4399, I noticed I cant see value of `arg` in my IDE, **I checked optimization is disabled and /DEBUG option is on.**

I also looked disassembly  and I do see `arg` have a value, code was executed.

I also tried to debug in both VS2013 and VS2017, both are the same.

PDB is loaded, I can also see some var,but many is missing

so in this case, where is the problem at? why I cant see the value from IDE?

Line 4399:

```
PyObject *arg = ((void)(lltrace &&  prtrace((*pp_stack)[-1], "ext_pop")), *--(*pp_stack));
```

[image]

[image]

[image: PDB is loaded but I can see only some of the variable]

Comment: Was the debugger able to load debuging symbols? Do you have a .pdb file?

Comment: screenshots of code are generally unreadable.

Comment: yes,  PDB is loaded, I can also see some var,but  many is missing @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this is the source code of python

Comment: python is written in c not in c++

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: they can be useful in demonstrating what is happening in the UI of an IDE though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters true, but the actual code must be pasted as text as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: but this is *not a question about the code.*. This is a question about the debugger in the IDE, when applied to the compiled binary and source code of a well-known Open Source project.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre posted as you ask, however the problem is not at any specific code, about half of the variable is not readable in IDE

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the issue here is why the IDE claims a specific symbol is undefined. I'm not versed enough in compilers and VS to answer with any kind of authority, but I suspect it may have to do with optimisations, where there is no assignment to anything anymore but `arg` is used to directly locate the method to call.

Comment: sometimes when you set debug, you have to clean your objects. VC++ didn't have this issue, but an object cleanup & retry wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I did try to rebuild solution, still same result :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging with VS2013 on a program with no optimization but still there is no symbol in the current context for local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727989/debugging-with-vs2013-on-a-program-with-no-optimization-but-still-there-is-no-sy)