# Debugging with VS2013 on a program with no optimization but still there is no symbol in the current context for local variables

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug Python2.7 to understand more about how python works.

when I trying to debug ceval.c at line 4399, I noticed I cant see value of `arg` in my IDE, **I checked optimization is disabled and /DEBUG option is on.**

1. I looked disassembly  and I do see `arg` have a value, code was
   executed.
2. I tried to debug in both VS2013 and VS2017, both are the same even
   PDB is loaded
3. I tried with WinDbg using `dv` command ,it's still unable to see any
   local variables

my compile command is :

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"H:\project\cpython-2.7\Include" /I"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PC" /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\python\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_CONSOLE" /D "WIN32" /D "_WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /GF /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\python\" /nologo /Fo"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\python\" /Fp"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\python\python_d.pch"
```

my link command is :

```
/OUT:"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCBuild\python_d.exe" /MANIFEST:NO /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCBuild\python_d.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCBuild\python27_d.lib" /STACK:"2000000" /DEBUG /BASE:"0x1d000000" /MACHINE:X86 /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBC" /SAFESEH /PGD:"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCBuild\python_d.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\python\python_d.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"H:\project\cpython-2.7\PCBuild\" /TLBID:1
```

so far I can only read `pp_stack` and `oparg`  ,I can't read value of any local variables

```
static PyObject *
call_function(PyObject ***pp_stack, int oparg
#ifdef WITH_TSC
                , uint64* pintr0, uint64* pintr1
#endif
                )
{
    int na = oparg & 0xff;
    int nk = (oparg>>8) & 0xff;
    int n = na + 2 * nk;
    PyObject **pfunc = (*pp_stack) - n - 1;
    PyObject *func = *pfunc;
    PyObject *x, *w;

    /* Always dispatch PyCFunction first, because these are
       presumed to be the most frequent callable object.
    */
    if (PyCFunction_Check(func) && nk == 0) {
        int flags = PyCFunction_GET_FLAGS(func);
        PyThreadState *tstate = PyThreadState_GET();

        PCALL(PCALL_CFUNCTION);
        if (flags & (METH_NOARGS | METH_O)) {
            PyCFunction meth = PyCFunction_GET_FUNCTION(func);
            PyObject *self = PyCFunction_GET_SELF(func);
            if (flags & METH_NOARGS && na == 0) {
                C_TRACE(x, (*meth)(self,NULL));
            }
            else if (flags & METH_O && na == 1) {
                //PyObject *arg = EXT_POP(*pp_stack);


                //EXT_POP-------------------
                PyObject *arg = (PyObject*)((void)(lltrace &&  prtrace((*pp_stack)[-1], "ext_pop")), *--(*pp_stack));
```

so in this case, where is the problem at? why I cant see the value from IDE?

[image]

[image]

[image: PDB is loaded but I can see only some of the variable]

Comment: `(void)` is suspicious in `arg = (PyObject*)((void)(lltr...`.  Unclear to its usefulness here.

Comment: BTW, picture does not match posted code in line 4399

Comment: @chux I dont see the difference between code in text and in picture... btw I dont think it's the problem about any specific code, should be something wrong in compiler settings I dont know...s